# Can you use the $username variable with rsync?

Tags: rsync

I have a directory with hundreds of usernames and need rsync to ignore certain folder like this.

```
/home/username/trash
```

The issue is there is hundreds of usernames and I can't just use the folder trash because that folder is used for other stuff as well.

I was hoping to use the $username variable

For example:

```
/home/$username/trash
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

This code is going in a ignore file for rsync.

This is a Centos 6/CPanel based server.

Comment: without any code, it is hard to help.

Comment: This si the default rsync program with Centos. The code will go into he exclude file. The rsync code is:

rsync --delete --exclude-from '/root/exclude-list.txt' -vae ssh 12.123.123.123:/backup/cpbackup/daily /backup/

The exclude file is where the new code will go. It has this now:

tmp/webalizer/*
homedir/logs/*
boxtrapper/*
.trash
.Trash
error_log
error.txt
homedir/mail/cur/*
homedir/mail/new/*
homedir/mail/tmp/*
application_backups/*


Thanks for the reply.